# Curl - Couldn't resolve host on Ubuntu for Windows 10 but works on windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, bash, curl

I run a bash shell on Ubuntu from Windows 10. I was recently provisioned a new laptop and now find that I am unable to retrieve URL's with curl.

However curl works when run directly on windows shell as opposed to ubuntu bash running on windows 10.

Additionally wget works on ubuntu for Windows. See below.

```
root@ionwuka2go2:/mnt/c/home/oneD/translator# curl https://basex.org
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: basex.org
root@ionwuka2go2:/mnt/c/home/oneD/translator# wget --spider https://basex.org
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2021-02-13 09:23:33--  https://basex.org/
Resolving basex.org (basex.org)... 185.221.106.187
Connecting to basex.org (basex.org)|185.221.106.187|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 14364 (14K) [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.
```

Comment: Are you using a VPN?  A third-party firewall or antivirus?  A proxy?

Comment: Something called BitDefender produced this message A program has been denied to connect to the Internet.Process path /usr/bin/curl. Protocol UDP (17). Port 53... .but I don't understand why that only applies to curl on ubuntu and not wget or curl on windows.

Comment: If you're using WSL (or Git), you should always use Windows Defender and the built-in firewall.  Other antivirus programs and firewalls tend not to understand WSL and break things, and in addition, many of them can cause security problems of their own.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Caused by running anti-malware software. See message below.

BitDefender produced this message A program has been denied to connect to the Internet.Process path /usr/bin/curl. Protocol UDP (17). Port 53.

My temporary fix is to uninstall it (I couldn't temporarily disable) until it can be looked into by our SysAdmin.

Comment: We're glad this is fixed for you, but please provide more information to make this a full answer. To begin with please include more information about which antimalware software was causing this. If you have more information about how you discovered that, it would help as well.